# Sending SOAP Web service authentication token with request

Tags: xml, web-services, security, soap, soapui

I am working with a SOAP web services interface for an educational student management product called PEPi (version 5). At the moment I am researching the API with SoapSonar 7 and SoapUI 5.4.

The Endpoint has a function that returns a 'SignOn' token when supplied valid credentials. I assume that this token needs to be attached to each subsequent request, but how do I do it ?

My immediate need is to know how I might do this through either of the tools, however under authentication they offer options such as 'Basic Authentication','Kerbros' and 'Digest' along with Cookies, Windows NTLM and SSL client certs. I cannot see how in either of these products I can place this token into subsequent requests or paste it into a token field under authentication somewhere.

The longer term question is how do I build this into the SOAP XML when actually building my application, this can possibly wait until I have understood the API properly.

I feel there is something basic I have missed here I have tried using the credentials that do generate a token from the API as arguments for the any of the Basic, Kebros and Digest options but no luck in SOAPSoanar or SoapUI

Sorry but I am a newbie with this

Angus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This soap API actually has no inbuilt security mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a Bearer.... token? Usually you attach authorization token to your request using header. I attach Authorization token in my REST requests using headers.  Those are REST APIs but should work about the same. Just click add new header. Name it "Authorization" and specify value of the token. 
Process of adding a header described [here](https://www.soapui.org/docs/functional-testing/teststep-reference/http-request/headers.html)
Let me know if that's the case or not.

Comment: Hi Gregory. Thanks for your response, I have tried this but had no luck. I was thinking I might need somehow to use actors in the soap envelope to pass the username and password onto the token end point first with each request.

Comment: can you provide example of the token and maybe a screenshot of your error?

Comment: It appears that this API has no security !